# Install sqlsrv extension in uwamp

Tags: php, windows, uwamp

I tried to install sqlsrv extension in UWAMP.

I added the extension tag `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` in dir: `wamp\bin\apache\php.ini` and I placed the file in: `uwamp\bin\php\php-5.6.18\ext` then I restarted the server.

After that `php.ini` deleted the tag `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` from the file and the extension is not enabled and not shown in `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in save the extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
the system each time when restart it will load the php_uwamp.ini and will overwrite the php.ini. so we have to save it in  php_uwamp.ini.